# Place of 3D in the grand scheme of things

Tags: discussion

We have been talking about 3D's inclusion lately. I would like to discuss this seriously. Im not entirely convinced that this community can handle general 3D.

Fist let me point out one thing. None of the people who I know who work with  3D primarily resonate well to their work being called graphic design. I know a few (more than 30) but not enough to be a statisticaly meaningful sample. that have the work descriptions of technical animator, industrial designer, 3D visualizer etc... So im not saying this means its not suitable for this site.

### Historical View

3d does not begins its roots in may separate places. It begins very early in the 1800's in fact. The early adopters of modern systems are engineers and media researchers. From here the technology pours down to animation studios and finally to general populace and graphic design.

If we look at this form a historical view we can say that 3d graphics is not part of mainstream graphic design until mid 2000 if even today. Whereas engineers and media companies start adoption in early 1980's late 70's and are already in full swing by 1990. Its also already in wide spread use by when i arrive at university in mid 90's, and deprecation of 2d in engineering starts to raise its head. First generation of computer gamers who saw 3d in games are here, but we will have to wait still a while until the generation who were kids when quake came out hit the workforce somewhere around 2000. In 2000-2006 this starts to hit more general use general computation power stars to hit the sweet spot.

So today one could argue 3d belongs just as much in graphic design than it belongs to engineering, tv/movie production or anything else really*. I can eat that argument. But still we are not all of 3D its a piece of technology that spreads over our societies on a bread brush. And is quite popular due to the 3d printing hype**.

### Unmet Need

There is clearly a unmet need in the stack exchange. Theres no place for general 3d modeling/rendering/application use questions. That is because of the spread. There's no single place for 3d questions. Currently Stackoverflow is eating code questions. The new in private beta Computer Graphics is positioned for the academic/technical questions that SO wont take. Engineering.SE is positioned to take care of engineering related use questions although currently its not filling the spot well. Then we have the Animation and Modelling proposal that would eat most of the slack. And then there's us, we could only serve to take some of the slack.

We could probably never accept the full range of 3D questions. Even if we could then traditional graphic design would suffocate. The fear is that this would fragment any possible hope for a good solution.

[image]

**Image 1**: quick and dirty visualization of spread, with speculative positioning of GD.SE

### Could we really handle it all?

Possibly most likely not. Consider:

> In Maya its possible to specify models curves with multiple end knots and without. Curves can also specify weights. Yet surface patches always have muti knot edges. Second, weights for surfaces do not propagate trough animation modifers but does so for curves.
>
> I would like to do patch modelling where ensuring that the surfaces can be easily sewn is important. This would be trivial without the multi knot requirement. It would make fitting of my curves easier. Is there a workaround for this oversight whilst keeping a all NURBS workflow. This NURBS requirement is important for my end result.

Or

> When doing curve motion path animation in Maya, my curve flow path suddenly flips. Is there a way that i can force the latice not to flip.

Both of these questions if answered properly have components that belong to SO or Computer Graphics maybe mathoverflow. In any case while we could accommodate many of the questions things like model rigging and animation export would fall out of scope, yet not really fit entirely anywhere else unless gamedev wants to fill the slack.

### And finally

This is site is called  **graphic design** not **graphic`s` design**. There is a small semantic difference. This is quite hard as it does not transcend language barriers.

---

**Footnotes**:

* We have people doing templates for cutting cloth in 3d. People designing  medical implants.

** How many of you have dreamed of printing 3D? How many have done it. I have, but that's because i can do it for free and i have the equipment at work. Id be much rather using the 5 or 6 axis CNC mill personally.